# ASP.NET MVC 3 routing issue - not allow controller in URL...

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the following code to achieve something like domain.com/actionName1, domain.com/actionName2 and so on to reach actions that reside in home controller.

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase("DefaultRoutes",
             "{action}",
             new { controller = "Home" },
             new { action = new homeActionConstraint() });
```

It works fine. But how do I **stop** user from entering **domain.com/home/actionName1** etc. and still reaching the action instead of 404 or something?

Comment: why would you want it to 404?

Comment: @nathangonzalez not necessarily 404 maybe. maybe 301 or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the default `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route that matches that URL.
(or constrain it to not match)

Comment: but I do need the default {controller}/{action}. Just not for home controller.

Comment: @progtick: Then you can add a constraint.

Comment: You could also make a separate route redirecting `Home/{action}` to `{action}`.

Comment: @SLaks ... which of course should be defined **before** the default route (controller/action/id) definition.

Answer (score 1):

take out the default route, just delete it and everything will stop working the normal way or you can map the default root to the 404 page you desire, however that is a little strange even for SO